# Form not displaying on front page of twenty seventeen

Tags: wordpress

I'm having problems getting the form we set up for contributions to show up on the front page (using the twenty seventeen wp template) -- have resorted to using a the 'page links to' plugin, but it's just a temp fix.  These were the instructions my hubs sent me, which don't seem to work.  THANKS!

Go to Contributions > Manage Contribution Pages > click Links next to your membership sign-up/renewal page > click Live Page. Copy the URL and insert it into an HTML link or menu.

Or click the Wordpress shortcode icon to insert a form into any page or post.

Answer (score 2):

For the TwentySeventeen theme to add content to the Home page we have a few options:

- Set the static front page option in Customizer to a page
- We can then have a widgetized front page controlled by the Theme Options in the Customizer

I tested this and  I can add the Page with the CiviCRM shortcode and set it to be the front page.  https://civi47.tadpole.cc/ shows an example of this.

However, if you are trying to set this as the second piece of content via the Theme Options - that does not work for me as well.  I suspect this is due to the way the theme is implementing its home page.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.7/contributions/online-contributions/#page-or-post-in-wordpress), you can do this as follows:

> You can easily embed your contribution page in a post or page on your
>   WordPress front-end site.
>
> 1. Login to the administration dashboard of your WordPress site.
> 2. Click on Pages or Posts > Add New
> 3. Click on the CiviCRM icon next to Upload / Insert
> 4. Select Contribution Page as your Frontend Element
> 5. Select the desired contribution page
> 6. Save the page or post, and your contribution page will automatically be embedded within your site's theme on that page.

Read more at: [Online contributions](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.7/contributions/online-contributions/)

Comment: Tried that, too, and it's still not populating the area on the twenty seventeen home page with the form.